# Constrain UIView in Xcode Interface Builder such that it is as large as "union" of its subviews

Tags: ios, ios7, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, xcode5.1

I would like to add a subview inside a storyboard as follows: it should contain a `UILabel` and a `UISwitch` and should be just large enough such that the two controls fit inside with a constant horizontal distance in between them.

To this end I do the following in Xcode 5.1.1's Interface Builder:

- add the view
- add the `UILabel` as its subview; add leading constraint to superview: 0; add constraint to center it vertically inside superview
- add the `UISwitch` as its subview; add trailing constraint to superview: 0; add horizontal distance constraint to `UILabel`: 40; add constraint to center it vertically inside superview

When I now ask IB to update all frames, the view receives layout height zero. How can I add constraints in IB (not programmatically) that ensure that the view is as large as the "union" of its two subviews?

Comment: I can achieve the desired layout by adding two constraints (for constant and manually calculated width and height respectively) to the view. However, this workaround is obviously quite unsatisfactory.

Comment: Does it help if you set the view's **Content Compression Resistance Priority** to 1000?

Comment: @KaelinColclasure Nops, unfortunately is does not seem to make a relevant difference.

Comment: Hrm, I see what you mean… Hopefully someone with more experience with using IB constraints will chime in, but AFAICT setting width and height constraints manually is as good as it gets in IB.